# Linux persistent drive

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, kde-plasma-5, persistent

I have been using a persistent Kali drive with a 3.0 254gb NXT usb. That set up turned out to be unbearably slow taking minutes to start up and after I got the desktop still taking forever to open applications as simple as the terminal. So after some research I found a forum with people saying they have the same issue. Seems this is just a downside to using Kali and it’s large size on a usb persistent and after adding encryption it’s rightfully even slower. Some fixed this issue by using mint as there live usb and forgetting about Kali. After some additional research I’ve decided to try and make my own hacking distribution for my unique needs with way less tools than Kali that will hopefully run better on a live persistent usb drive. My new distro would be based from Debian and use kde as my interface. Does anyone have experience with this and or can offer some help guiding me or with some tips? Im wondering if since Kali is based from Debian and I had this slow problem that my new distribution which is also based from Debian will have the same issue? And If KDE is to resource hungry?